# How to debug an entity's validation mapping in Symfony 2.4?

Tags: validation, symfony

I would like to determine whether an entity property is required or not.

Does anyone know how to access all of the constraints for a given entity property?

I want to check if the NotBlank constraint is active for a certain propery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## information:

You can check the mapping information for a class (or object) with the help of the service:

**[`validator.mapping.class_metadata_factory`](https://github.com/symfony/FrameworkBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/validator.xml#L9)**

The underlying class is:

`Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory`

The service provides a method **[`getMetadataFor()`](http://api.symfony.com/2.3/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.html#method_getMetadataFor)** that allows you to obtain the  active mapping metadata for a class (or object).

This method returns an instance of...

[`Symfony\Component\Validator\Mapping\ClassMetadata`](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Validator/Mapping/ClassMetadata.html)

... that provides a `getPropertyMetadata(string $property)` method that returns the Metadata for a given property name.

## example usage:

Inside a controller (or any other ContainerAware instance) you can do:

```
$factory          = $this->container->get('validator.mapping.class_metadata_factory');
$classMetadata    = $factory->getMetadataFor('Your\Bundle\Entity\Name');
$propertyMetadata = $classMetadata->getPropertyMetadata('propertyName');
```

Answer (score 0):

View the list of [Supported Validation Constraints Reference](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html#supported-constraints) from Symfony web site

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm trying to find all the constraints for a given property. I'm not sure how the constraint reference page will help

Comment: Maybe it [list](http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/Validator/Constraints.html) will be usefull for you?

Comment: @Victor he is trying to debug an entity ... He wants to see what properties are concretely mapped to which validation constraints and not what constraints exist in general. Therefore your current answer sadly doesn't provide any help here :)

Comment: So use PHPUnit for write testing code and testing entity. But if you use not a lot of constraints for this entity, check them all manually in your code

Answer (score 0):

You can try ladybug bundle. It is very easy to use and shows in detail and nicely to see all properties and info inside an object.

Comment: Just checked. From first look - it looks like regular `dump()`. What the difference?