# Custom constraint never checked against

Tags: php, validation, symfony

I'm trying to do a simple validator with his constraint.

**Constraint**

```
namespace Me\MyBundle\Validator\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

class MyConstraint extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'Grossière erreur';
}
```

**Validator**

```
namespace Me\MyBundle\Validator\Constraint;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class MyConstraintValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message)
            ->addViolation();
        return false;
    }
}
```

**Validation**

```
Me\MyBundle\Entity\MyEntity:
    properties:
        myField:
            - Length:
                min: 9
            - Me\MyBundle\Validator\Constraint\MyConstraint: ~
```

As you can see `myField` has 2 contraints, `Length` is checked but `MyConstraint` is never.

What could be wrong ? How can I debug that ?

(Symfony 2.5.9)

Comment: Have you checked whether your constraint is evaluated when the `Length` constraint passes? Also it could be that you need to add [`NotBlank` as well](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#using-the-new-validator).

Comment: That's what I've meant. I think your validator will never be called, if the previous constraints are not passed.

Comment: I understand, I had also `NotBlank` already, my constrain is actually not evaluated even without `Length`

Comment: Have you registered your custom validator in the `services.yml`as descibed [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html#constraint-validators-with-dependencies)?

Comment: from the docs seem optionally, i always do it. Give a try

Comment: I tried your code and working fine (without any service.yml addition) in as sf.2.5.8 (I think is same). I have in the config.yml     `validation:      { enable_annotations: true }` but i don't think that make the difference. Try this only check. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your time @Matteo I checked multiple settings with the validation previously with no change at all

Comment: Seems like something elsewhere is having my validator skipped. For info the form fails to render if I intentionally mistake the Validator class from the validation directives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by adding the `group` that was defined in my formType

```
- Me\MyBundle\Validator\Constraint\MyConstraint:
    groups: ['the_related_form']
```

`[Default]` didn't work, I don't understand why

Answer (score 1):

**Debugging tip:**

Inside your controller, use the following to get all the constraints for your property.

```
$factory          = $this->container->get('validator.mapping.class_metadata_factory');
$classMetadata    = $factory->getMetadataFor('Your\Bundle\Entity\Name');
$propertyMetadata = $classMetadata->getPropertyMetadata('propertyName');
```

([inspired by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270573/how-to-debug-an-entitys-validation-mapping-in-symfony-2-4))

If you see both constraints in `$propertyMetadata`, then perhaps Length interferes with the custom one, so try to run the code without the Length constraint.